# Why can't my discord bot see chat messages?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot to listen to Lofi Girl streams with friends in discord, but I don't understand why the bot doesn't see messages.

```
import discord
import youtube_dl

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.dm_messages = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True
intents.voice_states = True
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!play'):
        print(message.content)
        youtube_url = message.content[7:]
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(youtube_url, download=False)
            audio_url = info['url']

        voice_channel = message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_url))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!pause'):
        vc = message.guild.voice_client
        if vc.is_playing():
            vc.pause()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!resume'):
        vc = message.guild.voice_client
        if vc.is_paused():
            vc.resume()

client.run('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

No matter what I do, nothing works, I even tried to add more intents, but that didn't help either

Comment: Did you actually enable the message contents intent in the developer portal?

Comment: Privileged Gateway Intents? Yes, all.

Comment: You need to enable the message intents in dev portal as well as enabling in your code. You shouldn't be using multiple on_message events. In fact you should be using commands.Bot instead of Client and not handling anything other than printing in on_message